# Why is Kotlin accepting a null value in an attribute declared as a non-nullable string?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gson

I declared a `data class` like this:

```
data class Product(val name: String = "", val price: Float = 0f)
```

My code is:

```
val json = "{'name': null, 'price': 50.00}"
val gson = GsonBuilder().create()
val p = gson.fromJson(json, Product::class.java)
println("name is ${p.name}")
```

The console output is: `name is null`

How is this possible? 
The name attribute is not a nullable string.

Comment: Best guess is that Gson is using reflection, which would bypass normal `Intrinsics` checking. Everything is java bytecode under the hood, and there's no "non-nullable String" as far as java is concerned.

Comment: I'm not comfortable with JSon, but the first line of your code says `'name': null`. It may be the problem.

Comment: @BenP. It's a great guess, Ben. I suppose the only solution would be to use another deserializer.

Comment: Are you sure your `name` isn't the literal string "null"?

Comment: @Tenfour04 it's not a string, unfortunately

Comment: This is the reason I prefer Moshi over Gson. Gson write Null to non-nullable field where as Moshi fail-fast with null value.

Comment: @karthikk Reflection vs Code Generation. The eternal battle!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's common problem when using Gson with Kotlin - and the runtime errors occur far too late here, which may make your program unstable and crash-friendly. For example, write:

`val name: String = p.name`

Boom! Crash.

Gson simply, as per [super hacky implementation](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/internal/UnsafeAllocator.java), allocates memory for the class without calling the constructor, and later fills fields with values that are present in JSON using reflection.

This makes it possible to store `null` in Kotlin's not-null properties, and that can cause NPE at runtime. You can provide custom [TypeAdapter](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.0/com/google/gson/TypeAdapter.html) to disable reflection for your class.

Comment: "uses reflection to get class constructor, create instance" - that's not entirely true. What `Unsafe` does is allocate the memory for the class _without_ invoking the constructor. Then GSON uses reflection to set the fields. So if there is some initialization logic, like setting the default values as in this case, it will never get called.